# python smtp email not working

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am the following python script

```
import sys
from smtplib import SMTP              
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
class EmailSender():

  def send_email(self, msg_text):
    SMTPserver = ‘localhost'
    conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)       

    try:
      sender =     ‘someone@something.com'
      destination = 'someone2@something.com'
      text_subtype = 'plain'
      msg = MIMEText(msg_text, text_subtype)
      msg['Subject']= "subject"
      msg['From']   = sender
      msg['To'] = destination

      conn.sendmail(sender, [destination], msg.as_string())
    except Exception, exc:
      sys.exit( "mail failed; %s" % str(exc) ) # give a error message
    finally:
      conn.close()
```

The scripts runs gracefully without reporting any errors but I do not see anything in the mail.
Also the postfix is running

```
sudo postfix start
netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN'| grep 25
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.25           *.*                    LISTEN
```

Please spot my mistake. I call it via

```
email_sender = EmailSender()
email_sender.send_email("SOMETHING BROKE!")
```

Comment: Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: How do I check the spam under /var/mail ?

Comment: Is Postfix on your local computer configured correctly? Can you prove that by having other email clients send mail through it?

Comment: is that just your typo, or you have the ` and ' mixed up on some occasions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here is the deal. I edited the destination in above script to a gmail account and it worked like a charm. So what was the issue? the 'someone2@something.com' destination is basically backed by Microsoft email server. I tried sending an email via

```
echo "testing mail" | mailx -s "this is a test email from `hostname`" someone2@something.com
```

and saw it ending up in /var/email/user . There was a Delivery Failure Report which read:

Final-Recipient: rfc822; someone2@something.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; ....protection.outlook.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;  Service unavailable; Client host
     blocked using FBLW15; To request removal from this list
    please forward this message to delist@messaging.microsoft.com

So Microsoft was blocking the email to go out from my machine.